# WPF CanExecute not being called every time

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following code in my WPF Application that I use to enable or disable buttons on my UI

**XAML**

```
<Button x:Name="FirstButton" Command="{x:Static local:MyClass.CommandOne}"/>
<Button x:Name="FirstButton" Command="{x:Static local:MyClass.CommandTwo}"/>
```

**Code Behind**

```
CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(CommandOne, CommandOne_Executed, CommandOne_CanExecute));
CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(CommandTwo, CommandTwo_Executed, CommandTwo_CanExecute));

public static readonly RoutedUICommand CommandOne = new RoutedUICommand();
public static readonly RoutedUICommand CommandTwo = new RoutedUICommand();

private void CommandOne_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e != null)
        e.CanExecute = (_currentValue > 1);
}

private void CommandTwo_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e != null)
        e.CanExecute = (_currentValue > 100);
}
```

**Worker Code**

```
private async Task DoSomeWork(int value)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // Do some work on value
        _currentValue = value
    }
}
```

What I find is that when the values of _currentValue change due to some processing sometimes the CommandOne_CanExecute and CommandTwo_CanExecute functions do not get called.  If I then e.g. move the UI they will then be called.  How can I ensure that these are called everytime.

Comment: Can you post _currentValue  full property code ?

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using these types of commands? Usually they go into your `ViewModel`? I use my own `ICommand` implementations which allows me to handle when to call `Can Execute Changed`. Here is a [link to such implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22286816/2029607)

Comment: A similar thing has occured to me.  Try calling `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` in your code-behind after executing a command. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331622/weird-problem-where-button-does-not-get-re-enabled-unless-the-mouse-is-clicked

Comment: @MickyD bare in mind that call `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` is an expensive method as it will refresh everything on the screen.

Comment: @XAMlMAX Agreed.  However in some cases there was no alternative

Answer (score 3):

You could call the `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` method to invalidate *all* commands.

What you should do however is to implement your own command - it is simply a class that implements the `ICommand` interface - and raise the `CanExecuteChanged` event of the command whenever you want the `CanExecute` method to get called.

Or you could use any of the implementations of the `ICommand` that are included in any of the MVVM frameworks out there. You could for example take a look at how the `RelayCommand` class is implemented in MvvmLight: https://github.com/paulcbetts/mvvmlight/blob/master/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(NET35)/Command/RelayCommand.cs.

It has a `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` method that you can call to raise the `CanExecuteChanged` event of the command. This will cause the `CanExecute` method to get invoked and the command to be invalidated.

The built-in `RoutedUICommand` class has no such method I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a property for CurrentValue instead of a variable and raisecanexecutechanged event
Try below code

```
    private int _currentValue = false;
    public bool CurrentValue
    {
        get { return _currentValue; }
        set 
          { 
              if(_currentValue != value)
                CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
              SetProperty(ref _currentValue, value); 

          }
    }

CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(CommandOne, CommandOne_Executed, CommandOne_CanExecute));
CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(CommandTwo, CommandTwo_Executed, CommandTwo_CanExecute));

public static readonly RoutedUICommand CommandOne = new RoutedUICommand();
public static readonly RoutedUICommand CommandTwo = new RoutedUICommand();

private void CommandOne_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e != null)
        e.CanExecute = (CurrentValue > 1);
}

private void CommandTwo_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e != null)
        e.CanExecute = (CurrentValue > 100);
}

private async Task DoSomeWork(int value)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // Do some work on value
        CurrentValue = value
    }
}
```

Comment: CommandOne.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(); gives the error Error CS1061 'RoutedUICommand' does not contain a definition for 'RaiseCanExecuteChanged' and no extension method 'RaiseCanExecuteChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'RoutedUICommand' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @HarryBoy my mistake RoutedUICommand do not has a built-in RaiseCanExecuteChanged I think you need to use InvalidateRequerySuggested