# Controls appear inactive when changing content

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm using a ContentControl to display various ViewModels, which all use DataTemplates for view generation.
Now the problem is, after i change the content (by clicking on a hyperlink for example), things such as hyperlinks appear inactive (i.e. grayed out), until i click on the UI again. Is there any way to avoid this behaviour without having to simulate a mouseclick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having <s>the same</s> a very similar problem and haven't yet fixed it, but it does sound like calling CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested() *might* help you out.

[Here's my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331622/weird-problem-where-button-does-not-get-re-enabled-unless-the-mouse-is-clicked) this week that is similar, I think.  unforgiven3 linked me to [his question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751966/commandmanager-invalidaterequerysuggested-isnt-fast-enough-what-can-i-do) as well.

Although there might be some question about whether or not the CommandManager route is the way to go, as I mentioned in my question's edited text, [Laurent Bugnion's MVVM Light Toolkit](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/06/14/mvvm-lsquolightrsquo-toolkit-for-wpf-and-silverlight.aspx) relies on this mechanism to do his command binding updates.