# CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested() not working

Tags: wpf, icommand

I have my command's **CanExecute** method called only once when the wpf app starts. I want to be able to re-evaluate that method periodically. I found some references to calling **CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()** either programmatically or with a **DispatcherTimer**. Neither works for me and CanExecute is only called once per app lifetime.

Anyone know a fix?

-pom-

Comment: Maybe need to call via `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke?` http://stackoverflow.com/a/15828850

Answer (score 3):

I've read about that technique, but it's not one that I've used or that I think is commonly used.  Normally I would use DelegateCommand from Prism, or RelayCommand from MVVM light.  These implement ICommand which has the CanExecuteChanged event.  You are then responsible for raising this event when the state of your view model changes, e.g.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   DelegateCommand _myCommand;

   public MyViewModel()
   {
      _myCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteMyCommand, CanExecuteMyCommand);
   }

   public ICommand MyCommand
   {
       get{ return _myCommand; }
   }

   private void ExecuteMyCommand(){ ... }
   private bool CanExecuteMyCommand() { return true/false; }

   // for example
   public int SomeProperty
   { 
      get{ ... }
      set{  
         ...;
         if( ... ){
            _myCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Not quite what you were after, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Good to know, thanks for the answer! I'll accept that in a few days unless a non-framework answer pops up. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, at least the RelayCommand from MVVMLight internally uses the CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested so it makes no difference in using RaiseCanExecuteChanged or the one from command manager. (I tried posting the actual code in the comment but it looks doesn't take formatting but try decompiling it and you'll see what I mean)