# MVVM Validation With Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

i'm currently working on a project using MVVM and Entity Framework Code First Model. So i implemented IDataErrorInfo and INotifyPropertyChanged in my model classes. Now, in my viewmodel i implemented a SaveCommand and a CanSave boolean method, my question is how can i raise canexecutechanged for the whole entity and not individual properties? since my properties already implemented InotifyPropertyChanged in model.

This is my Model Class

```
 public class Guest:ValidatableBindableClass
{
    //my properties here
    //implement InotifyPropertyChanged and IDataErrorInfo
}
```

This is my ViewModelClass:

```
 public class AddEditGuestViewModel:BindableClass
{
    private Hospede guest;
    public RelayCommand SaveCommand  { get; set; }
    private readonly Hmsdb.HMS context = new Hmsdb.HMS();

    public Hospede Guest
    {
        get { return guest; }
        set { SetProperty(ref guest, value, propertyName: "Guest"); }
    }

    private void OnSave()
    {

        context.Hospedes.Add(Guest);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    private bool CanSave()
    {
        return context.Entry(Guest)
            .GetValidationResult().IsValid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't post images of code. Copy the relevant code into the question and format accordingly. Just posting images reduces the searchability of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can raise the `PropertyChanged` event for all properties by passing `null` or `string.Empty` to the constructor of the `PropertyChangedEventArgs`:

```
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(null));
```

You will need to call the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` method of each `RelayCommand` though.

Comment: Depending on the command implementation, a call to `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` might be enough..

Comment: It is pretty ineffective though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751966/commandmanager-invalidaterequerysuggested-isnt-fast-enough-what-can-i-do. And the entity seems to have only one command anyway.

Comment: My model class already implements propertychanged event for each property, the question is how can i rise canexecute changed on viewmodel class sinse i´m binding to guest entity and not Gues.SomeProperty? Thanks for replay...

Comment: Raise CanExecuteChanged from where?

Comment: @mm8 from ViewModel

Comment: @mm8 Guest is the Entity Model Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and IDataErrorInfo not the ViewmModel

Comment: What are you talking about? Again: from where (which class) are trying to raise the event?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140064/discussion-between-gonguela-and-mm8).